# Save information from sprintf to a variable

Tags: c, command-line, filenames, printf, inode

is it possible to save information gather from a sprintf into a variable? The lines of code below are an example to better illustrate my question.

```
char fileName;
fileName = sprintf(command, "find -inum %i -type f", iNode);
```

The purpose is to find the file name associated with the inode number, then run "stat" on that file name.

Comment: Can't you just use the `command` variable afterwards?

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`popen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) function.

Comment: I am using the popen function in the overall program, but running into issues with it. Trying to see if there are other alternatives.

Comment: Then maybe you should post a question about those issues instead? All `sprintf` does is format a string, it doesn't run the program for you.

Comment: @templatetypedef can you be more specific in your answer? I am not sure what you mean by "use command variable afterwards".

Comment: @seiryuu10- I guess I don't understand your question.  When you call `sprintf`, you produce a formatting string.  It doesn't make any system calls.  I don't get what you mean when you ask "save information gather from a sprintf into a variable," since `sprintf`'s entire point is to write a string to a variable.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: If I would venture a guess as to the problem with the `popen` call you apparently have, it's that the syntax of the `find` command is wrong. You forgot the _path_ from where to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
FILE *fp;
char cmd[1024];
char filename[1024];

sprintf(cmd, "find -inum %i -type f", iNode);
fp = popen(cmd);
fgets(filename, sizeof filename, fp);
pclose(fp);
```

At the end of this code, `filename` will contain the fist line produced by the `cmd`.

Comment: I tried this line of code and added fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", filename); and I just got a blank line. Is this line of code incorrect?

Comment: I don't have a UNIX box handy for testing.  If you do the `find` in the shell what does it produce?

Comment: 'find -inum 148869 -type f' produces './test.c'

Comment: Not sure why its not working.  Suggest you changing `fgets` into `while (NULL != fgets(...))` and printing each line.  Sorry can't be more helpful.