# Not printing Inode File name or header information in C

Tags: c, project, printf, inode

Running the following lines of code and running into issues that I am not sure about. The main idea is for a user to enter in an inode to be searched. Once found, the file name associated with that inode is printed, then the command "stat" is ran on that file name to produce info on that file.

```
#define COMMAND_LEN 1024
#define DATA_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *pf;
    char command[COMMAND_LEN];
    char data[DATA_SIZE];
    char inode_data[DATA_SIZE];
    int iNode;

    printf("Enter inode: ");
    scanf(argv[0], iNode);

    sprintf(command, "find -inum %i -type f", iNode);
    pf = popen(command, "r");

    if(!pf){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open pipe for outlet.\n");
        return;
    }

    fgets(data, DATA_SIZE, pf);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", data);

    sprintf(command, "stat %s", data);
    pf = popen(command, "r");
    fgets(inode_data, DATA_SIZE, pf);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", inode_data);

    if (pclose(pf) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to close command stream!\n");

    Return 0;
}
```

Once I compile, run, and enter an inode number, I get the following:

```
Enter inode: 148869

stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.

Error: Failed to close command stream!
```

Received useful help from perivous question post [Save information from sprintf to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785225/save-information-from-sprintf-to-a-variable#14785279)

Comment: The purpose of the `stat` utility is to give you access to the `stat` system call from the shell.  Since you are writing code in C, it makes a lot more sense to just call `stat` instead of spawning a shell to call it for you. `man 2 stat`

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `scanf` with the `argv[0]` parameter unless you passed a format string in the command line arguments. Also, scanf should pass an int* as the second parameter, so it sould really be `scanf("%d", &iNode);`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [`find` manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) you see that it needs a *path* from where to search. You do not have that in your `find` command line.

You also don't read the input from the user correct. `argv[0]` is the name of your program. You should pass a proper formatting string, e.g.

```
scanf("%s", iNode);
```

If you used a debugger, or even printed out the input after `scanf`, you should have seen this very quickly.

Comment: I originally used sprintf(command, "find / -inum %i -type f", iNode); before, but the search game me the file and anything else in the directory that came close to the inode.

Comment: @seiryuu10 Do you have multiple disks mounted? Remember that an inode number is only unique for a single filesystem. Multiple filesystems may have files with the same inode number.

Comment: I am running in a VM for this project. So, it is only accessing the directory of what is within the VM.

Comment: @seiryuu10 Then it's probably because you don't read the input from the user correctly.